# Como publicar uma aplicação python

Tags: python, django

Boa tarde:

estou querendo desenvolver uma aplicação com python (django) minha preocupação é como vou publicar minha aplicação (será web), por que python é interpretado, mas não posso mandar meu fontes pro servidor.

existe algum forma de resolver esse problema?

Grato:
Paulo

Comment: Em essência não, achei que esta questão já estava superada. Hoje quase todas linguagens podem ser revertidas para o fonte mesmo sem ter os fontes. C, C++, Rust e algumas poucas outras ainda não são fáceis, mas pode reverter com um pouco de esforço e aceitação que não terá tanta qualidade. Mas se ainda acha isso muito importante pode jogar fora tudo o que fez e fazer em alguma dessas linguagens, segura um pouco mais. Alguém falará que tem como, é só uma forma de ofuscar um pouco, não protege nada, se alguém quiser mesmo ver o que você fez ela fará normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai mandar seus fontes para o servido*r*, e não tem nenhum problema com isso.
De fato você está com as preocupações erradas - e, como sua pergutna tem só duas linhas, não consigo entender quais conceitos você ainda precisa ver.

Mas aplicações em Javascript, PHP, Python e Ruby em conjunto devem ser mais de 95% de toda a Web - e em todas elas o código fonte fica no servidor - e qualquer um que possa acessar o servidor com um usuário que tenha acesso aos arquivos pode ler o código fonte.

Um conceito que você talvez não tenha estudado bastante é justamente o de *quem* tem acesso ao servidor, e mesmo sendo um servidor com vários usuários, há como restringir a leitura dos arquivos apenas ao dono dos mesmos e ao super-usuário.

Mais recentemente, no entanto, se popularizaram os servidores virtuais rivados, ou ainda containers, em que, com o mesmo custo de hospedagem, você é pode ser a única pessoa com acesso ao servidor (e portanto ao código fonte) - é o caso das máqunas funcionando na Amazon, no OpenShift da RedHat, no Heroku, e Digital Ocean, dentre dezenas de outros provedores.

O modelo antigo, muito usado no Brasil para projetos em PHP, em que o cliente ganhava uma conta de usuário em um servidor compartilhado e só tinha acesso via FTP, não serve para publicar projetos em Python, em que o acesso ao shell é, em geral, necessário. Mas mesmo nesses casos o acesso aos arquivos de código fonte é restrito ao títular da conta.

Quanto a como colocar seu projeto em produção, a recomendação é buscar isso na docuemntação dos projetos que está usando, ou do serviço de hospedagem que contratar - uma vez que é um assunto muito amplo, e não tem como abordar numa única resposta de pergunta aqui.